# What is this position called in Yoga or gymnastics?

Tags: yoga, gymnastics

What is this position called in Yoga or gymnastics? I am trying to figure out.

[image: hands making the shape of a triangle, beach, yoga mats, cloudy]

Answer (score 4):

[Urdhva Hastasana](https://www.yogajournal.com/poses/upward-salute/) is the corresponding Asana in yoga, as often seen during sun salutations.